# Is it a best practice to have edit and create actions in same view?

Tags: php, laravel

In my previous project using Laravel, I've played a lot with RESTful and realized that I used some repeated logic in '**edit**' and '**create**' controllers and also many '**html**' in **views**. Then I came up with merging them into one file to avoid repeats. However, I found that doing so would somehow mess things up as I had to add lots of logic.

So, what is the best practice here? Do your guys usually separate them into two files or using a same file more often?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends how you manage your frontend. With a RESTful API, and some JS framework like  AngularJS, you can only have one page for edit/create, it just doesn't need a mass of code.
If your creation or edition is the same, you do not need to separate them.

I actually work on a Webmail, and our contact edition page is the same than our edition page.

Comment: I am not familiar with AngularJS however I am about to use Backbone on my project to create one page app. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Really depends.

The difference between my edition/creation forms are usually just an method input, so usually I use the same file.

But I think when you have really different content for this two actions, you should have two separated files.